# How to constrain a variable to be one of the types in an enum

Tags: typescript

How can implement a generic type which constraints the value of the variable to be any of the types in the enum?

```
enum SexTypes {
    Male,
    Female
}
```

This would be the type to implement:

```
type TApplyEnumConstraint<T> ........
```

To achieve this:

```
let sex: TApplyEnumConstraint<SexTypes> = "Male"  // ==> OK
let sex: TApplyEnumConstraint<SexTypes> = "Female"  // ==> OK
let sex: TApplyEnumConstraint<SexTypes> = "foo"  // ==> Error
```

Comment: Do you actually _want_ an enum here? Typically you'd use the enum itself, `let sex: SexTypes = ...`. In this case maybe `type SexTypes = "Male" | "Female";` meets your needs better?

Comment: Right That would be the same in this case, but I would like to know how to work with enums. In case I want to constraint according to the enum types which are already created

Comment: Then why aren't you _using the enum_, `let sex: SexTypes = SexTypes.Male`? If this is runtime data the types will have been erased anyway.

Comment: I found a way to convert the enum to a string union type as:
type TSexTypes= keyof typeof Sextypes. Using this, works but I would like if there is a way to convert this to generic so I can transform any enum to union of strings of it's type keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments a union type would probably fit better:

```
type SexTypes = "Male" | "Female";
```

If you want to stick to your enum approach what you can do is *convert* your enum to a union type using string literals. That way you would get the same result as above but still have your enum for whatever reason. However you would have to define enum values first for this.

```
enum SexTypes {
  Male = "Male",
  Female = "Female"
}

const sex1: `${SexTypes}` = "Female";
const sex2: `${SexTypes}` = "Male";
const sex3: `${SexTypes}` = "foo";
//    ~~~~ -> Type '"foo"' is not assignable to type '"Male" | "Female"'.
```

If you want to keep the generic it get's a little more complicated:

```
enum SexTypes {
  Male = "Male",
  Female = "Female"
}

type TApplyEnumConstraint<T> = T extends string
  ? string extends T
    ? never
    : `${T}`
  : never;

const sex4: TApplyEnumConstraint<SexTypes> = "Female";
const sex5: TApplyEnumConstraint<SexTypes> = "Male";
const sex6: TApplyEnumConstraint<SexTypes> = "foo";
//    ~~~~ -> Type '"foo"' is not assignable to type '"Male" | "Female"'.
```

Note: You can also replace the string literals with `keyof typeof SexTypes`. You will get the same union type result. (=`"Male" | "Female"`)

```
const sex: keyof typeof SexTypes = "Female";
```

Comment: Thats really nice! Thank you, do you think is there a way to use "keyof typeof T" instead of using string literals?

Comment: Yes of course, I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks! But that wouldn't be really generic as you are tied to SexTypes

Comment: You're right, I completely overlooked that.